# How to fix 'Don't know about xamarin.forms.view' creating Tables?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I'm making some kind of selling app and I need to register some info about the client with SQLite, product and so on. What happens is that I'm getting the error **"System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about xamarin.forms.view"** when I click on the button to save these info on the database.
Here is the code where the error message appears:

````
```using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using SQLite;


namespace VendasEstoque.Banco
{
    class AcessoBanco
    {
        private SQLiteConnection _conexao;

        public AcessoBanco()
        {
            var dep = DependencyService.Get<ICaminho>();
            string caminho = dep.ObterCaminho("database.sqlite");


            _conexao = new SQLiteConnection(caminho);
            _conexao.CreateTables<Clientes, Produtos, Vendas>();
````

Clentes.cs:

```
using SQLite;

namespace VendasEstoque
{
    [Table("Clientes")]
    public class Clientes
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Cli_Id { get; set; }
        public string Cli_Nome { get; set; }
        public int Cli_Cpfcnpj { get; set; }

        public string Cli_Telefone { get; set; }
        public string Cli_Celular { get; set; }
        public string Cli_Data { get; set; }
        public string Cli_Email { get; set; }
        public string Cli_Obs { get; set; }
        public string Cli_Status { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Produtos.cs:

```
namespace VendasEstoque
{
    [Table("Produtos")]
    public class Produtos
    {
        public string ProdNome { get; set; }
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ProdId { get; set; }
        public string ProdDesc { get; set; }
        public int ProdQtde { get; set; }
        public float ProdPrecoCompra { get; set; }
        public float ProdPrecoVenda { get; set; }
        public string FormaPagamento { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Vendas.cs:

```
[Table("Vendas")]
    public partial class Vendas
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int VendaId { get; set; }
        public string ProdDesc { get; set; }
        public int ProdQtde { get; set; }
        public string Teste { get; set; }
        public string FormaPagmento { get; set; }

        public string CliId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What plugin did u use in your xamarin project? sqlite-net-pcl ?

Comment: @Adlorem Yes, sqlite-net-pcl

Comment: please show the code for `Clientes, Produtos, Vendas`

Comment: @Jason Added to the post.

Comment: why is `Vendas` a partial class?  Do you also have other classes/pages in the project that have the same name as these classes?

Comment: I only have these three classes for the table creations. I first tried to make the Vendas a simple class, but it says that the 'partial modifier is missing'.

Comment: do you also have a page named Vendas?

Comment: No, but I do have a page named Venda, without 's'.

Comment: Are you sure that the class (not the file) of that page is not also Vendas?  Because somewhere in your project is another class named Vendas that is confusing SQL.  Either find it and fix it, or rename your Vendas Model to something else (like VendasModel) to eliminate the ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The other page was also being renamed with the Vendas class.